# Can I turn on my Android phone from my computer?

Tags: power-on

I have an Android phone (Moto Z) and for some reason the buttons stopped responding. This wasn't an actual issue until one night I let the battery die... the phone accepts the charger AND charges but since the buttons don't work I can't turn it on.

When I plug the phone into my computer, and I can see it as a USB device (lsblk). What now? Is there a way to issue a command to the device from my computer (Arch Linux) telling it to turn on?

Comment: I'm afraid no. You need some kind of recovery devices to contact your device via special pins on the motherboard.

Comment: So basically I have a brick. This is my 3rd Moto Z and I have to say, I cannot recommend it. :) thanks for the comment.

Comment: I'm sad to hear that and sad to say this, but it's probably... a brick, unless you have those professional repair tools or bring it to something who has them.

Comment: You could just get the power button fixed.

Comment: Is USB debugging enabled in Settings?  I think it is possible to boot up the device through ADB on PC.

Comment: @Lloyd Dominic: ADB is only available after the device has booted Android. Then you can reboot it via adb. However here the device is off (or in the loading state without running Android) - hence it has no adb interface.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation where the button didnt work. I actually managed to clean the button and make it work again. It will require some patience, but in this state you got nothing much to lose.

The button consists of 2 layers of conductors where 1 layer is actually a sphere and when pressing it bends down, touches the other layer and its registered as a click.

What happened is that somehow dirt got between those layers causing the 2 layers never to touch. If you carefully open up your phone, and then open up the layers and clean the dirt, you can fix your phone yourself.

Ofc there is no guarantee that this is the actual problem or that the fix will fully work, but if you can't do anything else I think its worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way if your phone is found when connected via USB (and has USB debugging enabled for that computer). First, get ADB tools.

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

Then, try one of these commands.

```
adb shell input keyevent 26
adb shell input keyevent 224
```

The screen should turn on or off with these commands.